# Redux Promise Middleware + Redux Mock Store Testing

Tags: unit-testing, redux

I tried to test an action creator that returns a promise, using also redux mock store.

```
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import nock from 'nock';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { domain, port } from '../../config/environment';

import { GET_ITEMS_START,
         GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS } from '../../constants/items';
import { getItems } from './items';

const promise = promiseMiddleware({
  promiseTypeSuffixes: ['START', 'SUCCESS', 'ERROR']
});

describe('Get Items', () => {
    it('should create GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS action after successfully getting items', (done) => {
      nock(`${domain}:${port}`)
        .get('/api/items')
        .reply(200, {
          _id: '1',
          text: 'Make Eggs',
          completed: false
        });

      const expectedActions = [
        { type: GET_ITEMS_START },
        { type: GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS, payload: {
          data: {  _id: '1', text: 'Make Eggs', completed: false }
        }}
      ];

      const store = mockStore({}, expectedActions, done);
      store.dispatch(getItems());
    });
  });
```

and here is my action creator code

```
export function getItems() {
  return {
    type: GET_ITEMS,
    payload: {
      promise: axios.get(`${domain}:${port}/api/items`)
    }
  };
}
```

but the result is mismatch because the promise resolved a deep nested objects

```
  Error: Expected { payload: { config: { headers: {}, method: 'get', timeout: 0, transformRequest: [ [Function] ], transformResponse: [ [Function] ], url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/items', withCredentials: undefined }, data: { _id: '1', completed: false, text: 'Make Eggs' }, headers: {}, status: 200, statusText: 'OK' }, type: 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS' } to equal { payload: { data: { _id: '1', completed: false, text: 'Make Eggs' } }, type: 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS' }
  + expected - actual

   {
     "payload": {
  -    "config": {
  -      "headers": {}
  -      "method": "get"
  -      "timeout": 0
  -      "transformRequest": [
  -        [Function]
  -      ]
  -      "transformResponse": [
  -        [Function]
  -      ]
  -      "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/items"
  -      "withCredentials": [undefined]
  -    }
       "data": {
         "_id": "1"
         "completed": false
         "text": "Make Eggs"
       }
  -    "headers": {}
  -    "status": 200
  -    "statusText": "OK"
     }
     "type": "GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS"
   }
```

I obviously don't want to copy all of those deep nested properties into my test suite.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing a unit test, you probably don't need to call the actual REST API. Instead you can mock axios and make it return some fake data which won't be so deep.

Comment: Can you give me a specific example on mocking the axios?

Comment: Here's one guide: http://kentor.me/posts/testing-react-and-flux-applications-with-karma-and-webpack/ 
Here's another: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax
And another: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/60

Comment: thanks. the first link looks promising. I'll report back once I try it